# Check if array contain other array (for multidimensional array) php

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking forward to compare two arrays in PHP.

For example, I have array A:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 19
            [sub_option_id] => 57
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 1093
            [sub_option_id] => 3582
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 1093
            [sub_option_id] => 57
        )

)
```

And array B:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_option_detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [option_id] => 19
                            [sub_option_id] => 57
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [option_id] => 1093
                            [sub_option_id] => 57
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [option_id] => 1093
                            [sub_option_id] => 3582
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_option_detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [option_id] => 1
                            [sub_option_id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

By looking at the data structure, I can see that array B contains array A. How can I achieve the same analysis using PHP, ie how to check array B contain array A?

Please help me if you know!
Thank you so much!

Comment: @EbinManuval array_intersect only works on flat arrays and with a single value. This is a multidimensional array with two values/keys to check. Same thing with array_diff

Comment: This topic not same issue for my topic.

Comment: @DavidWinder It work perfectly! Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function for array compare:

```
function array_equal($a, $b) {
    if (!is_array($a) || !is_array($b) || count($a) != count($b))
        return false;
    $a = array_map("json_encode", $a);
    $b = array_map("json_encode", $b);
    return array_diff($a, $b) === array_diff($b, $a); // mean both the same values
}
```

And then use it as:

```
$details = array_column($arrayB, 'order_option_detail');
foreach($details as $detail){ // loop the two items.
    if (array_equal($detail, $arrayA)) {
       // Do what ever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From arrayB you only need 'order_option_detail'.

So if we use array_column we can get those isolated.

```
$details = array_column($arrayB, 'order_option_detail');
foreach($details as $detail){ // loop the two items.
    if($detail === $arrayA){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/TW670

Comment: Thank you, But please see index of array A and array B, they can not same index

Comment: That was my mistake. I thought they where the same and I just copied one array to the other. This is the correct output: https://3v4l.org/TW670

Comment: I changed index of array in this link so it return null.

Comment: please help me @Andreas

Comment: Don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Please see link https://3v4l.org/TW670. I want it still return true

Comment: I changed index of $arrayA

Comment: please check https://3v4l.org/fJ4AX @Andreas

Comment: Check if your last solution with `checkArr` valid also when array has duplicate element